# Subgroup generated by d where d is greatest common divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Can anyone check if my proof is right? Any help would be appreciated.

Problem: Show that the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by any finite set of nonzero integers $n_1,…, n_k$ is $\mathbb{Z}d$, where $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $\{n_1,…, n_k\}$.

Proof: Let $H$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$. Then $H$ is either $\{0\}$ or there is a unique positive integer that generates $H$. So, we claim, $H = \{n_1,…, n_k\} = \mathbb{Z}d$, where $d = \gcd (n_1,…, n_k)$. By definition of the greatest common divisor, $d|n_1, d|n_2,……,d|n_k$. That is, $n_1 = (a_1)d$ for some integer $a_1$, $n_2 = (a_2)d$ for some integer $a_1$ and $a_2$. Thus, we can go on until $n_k= (a_k)d$ for some integer $(a_k)$. We know  $H = \{n_1,…, n_k\}$, then $H = \{n_1,…, n_k\} = \{ (a_1)d,….,(a_k)d\} = \{(a_j)d | (a_j) ≠0 \in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Hence $H = \mathbb{Z}d$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $H_d$ be the group generated by $d$. Then $H$ is a subgroup of $H_d$. This is I think all that has been shown, and it can be shown more briefly: every element of $H$ is divisible by $d$.

But we need to show that $H=H_d$.

Let $e$ be the positive generator of $H$. Then $d$ divides $e$. Since $e$ divides all the $n_i$, we cannot have $e\gt d$, for that would contradict the fact that $d$ is the *greatest* common divisor of the $n_i$. Thus $d=e$.

**Remark:** In number-theoretic terms, what we are proving is that $d\in H$, that is, that $d$ can be expressed as $\sum x_i n_i$, where the $x_i$ are integers.